# How to multiply matrix and constant matrix in R

Tags: r

I have 15*2 "gamma matrix" and  1*1 "Y-w" matrix. I have certain difficulty in multiplying them, Anyone can help me please . Is there any method to convert 1*1 matrix to constant.

Comment: `as.vector(onebyonematrixname)`

Comment: It still a vector of 1*1 , I need constant here.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, there is no such thing as a constant in R. A vector is the lowest atomic form available.

Answer (score 3):

Should be OK if follow the comments.

```
> m1 = matrix(1:12,4,3); m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12
> m2 = matrix(2,1,1); m2
     [,1]
[1,]    2
> m1 * as.vector(m2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2   10   18
[2,]    4   12   20
[3,]    6   14   22
[4,]    8   16   24
```

Comment: Thanks it works this way but diag can also be used.

Comment: `m1 * c(m2)` would also work. And also `m1 * drop(m2)`

Comment: Another thing is not to mix up %*% and *